# MongoDB query double nested array

Tags: mongodb, multidimensional-array

Below is my mongo db document named business

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5be8e24a6600321ead321466"),
  "business_id": "r89Re4FNgVWHgBfjCVZyVw",
  "name": "Harlow",
  "neighborhood": "Ville-Marie",
  "address": "438 Place Jacques Cartier",
  "city": "Montréal",
  "state": "QC",
  "postal_code": "H2Y 3B3",
  "stars": 3.5,
  "attributes": {
    "Alcohol": "full_bar",
    "BikeParking": "True",
    "BusinessAcceptsCreditCards": "True",
    "BusinessParking": "{'garage': False, 'street': False, 'validated': False, 'lot': False, 'valet': False}",
    "Caters": "False",
    "GoodForMeal": "{'dessert': False, 'latenight': False, 'lunch': False, 'dinner': False, 'breakfast': False, 'brunch': False}",
    "RestaurantsDelivery": "False",
    "RestaurantsGoodForGroups": "True",
  },
  "categories": "Nightlife, Bars, American (Traditional), Tapas/Small Plates, Poutineries, Supper Clubs, Restaurants, Tapas Bars",
}
```

Question:In the above collection named business i need to Find all restaurants which provides meal for lunch. (need to Check attributes-GoodForMeal-lunch)

it is nested array. please suggest me how can this be done with mongo db

Comment: There is no arrays in your sample. `"attributes.GoodForMeal.lunch": true` should work.

Comment: > db.business.find("attributes.GoodForMeal.lunch": true)
2018-12-01T16:19:45.399-0500 E QUERY    [js] SyntaxError: missing ) after argume
nt list @(shell):1:47

Comment: You should read on how to make basic queries with mongodb ... that `db.business.find("attributes.GoodForMeal.lunch": true) ` is wrong ... should be `db.business.find({"attributes.GoodForMeal.lunch": true})`